# Deciphering a substitution cipher if frequency analysis doesn't work (hypothetically)

Tags: substitution-cipher, frequency-analysis

If a text ciphered by substitution is in a artificial language with equal frequency distribution of characters, and perhaps 2 or 3-grams too, what would be the next, easy to understand, ways to decipher it?

I found the "*Hill climbing*" concept, of starting with a random set of replaces, compare results with a dictionary, try some changes and repeat (that seems like a *genetic algorithm* idea to me). But I would like to learn some other easy ideas.

PS: Looking for questions about it, I read something about "*word patterns*", but seems not too easy to code.

---

Edit: I have to add that I tried to find word patters in the book "*A pale blue dot*" by *Carl Sagan*. The pattern of the first 202 unique longest words in the book had only 1 match with a word in the dictionary (although I used a 80k words dictionary, so only 70 of that patterns matched a word there, Sagan seems to use infrequent long words).

Only the 203th longest unique word in the book had 2 possible words in my dictionary for its pattern. So, because I'm using a long text like a book, I have plenty of unique long words to create a substitution table, thus the method is easy to code.

Comment: Could you write the links that you found out?

Comment: @kelalaka Sure! I read about "word patterns" and "hill climbing" in this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/can-you-break-a-multi-language-code-using-frequency-analysis/9365#9365 I was thinking ways of coding that ideas now.